Is this matrix Kronecker product equation solvable?
Given a Hermitian matrix $A \in  \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. What can be said about the existence of a matrix $B \in  \mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$ such that
$$A\otimes B = cI$$
Here, $c\in [0,1]$. It is in the context of Kronecker product of two matrices.
My approach: For trivial case of $c=0$, $B=0_{m\times m}$ is a valid solution.
Query: What can be said if $c\neq 0$?

It can be said that the only such pairs $(A,B)$ are $A=uI$ and $B=\frac cuI$, for $u\ne 0$. This can be verified directly with the definition as a block-matrix in the link you've provided (with the others too).
